# получить список всех клиентов в локальной сети python

Tags: python, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер, tcp

Необходимо с помощью модуля socket получить список всех клиентов в локальной сети, а также, подключенных к серверу. В сетевом программировании новичок, найти решение не прошу, прошу предложить общую концепцию решения

Comment: начни со скана icmp

Comment: Клиентов какого рода? :)

Comment: socket это слишком обще. Приложения, протоколы разные бывают. Какие конкретно клиенты вас интересуют? Для примера посмотрите в сторону Bonjour (Zeroconf), Avahi использующих mDNS (multicast udp).